# Trivial (right or left) ideals of R imply that R is a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

It is clear that a division ring is simple, having only trivial right ideals.  It is also clear that if a ring, R, is unital and finite, having only trivial ideals, then the ring is a division ring.

However, is it true that a unital ring with only trivial right ideals is a division ring, with its order being irrelevant?

Comment: Two-sided or one-sided?

Comment: one-sided ideals.

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145655/29335

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $aR=R$ for all nonzero $a\in R$, and $R$ is unital. Fix $a\in R$; we seek an inverse. By hypothesis we know $1\in aR$ so $1=ab$ for some $b\in R$. And similarly $bR=R$ so $1=bc$ for some element $c\in R$. But then we have $a=abc=c$, so $1=ab$ and $1=ba$ and so arbitrary $a\in R$ have two-sided inverses, and hence $R$ is a division ring.

A symmetrical argument holds if we suppose $R=Ra$ for all nonzero $a\in R$.

A unital ring $R$ may fail to have two-sided ideals besides $0$ and $R$ and still fail to be a division ring due to the presence of zero divisors. The textbook examples are the matrix rings $M_n(k)$ (for any integer $n>1$) over any scalar field $k$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/why-is-the-ring-of-matrices-over-a-field-simple)). Indeed if $k$ is finite then so is $M_n(k)$!

Comment: Thank you for your help, Whacka!  It is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is meant by “A symmetrical arguments holds if...”? Do you mean to say we need not show $ab=ba$ if we suppose $R=Ra$ for all non-zero $a$?